# How to count the number of documents on date field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Scenario**: Consider, I have the following collection in the MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : "CustomeID_3723",    
    "IsActive" : "Y",
    "CreatedDateTime" : "2013-06-06T14:35:00Z"
}
```

Now I want to know the count of the created document on the particular day (say on 2013-03-04)
So, I am trying to find the solution using aggregation framework.

**Information**:
So far I have the following query built:

```
    collection.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            _id: '$CreatedDateTime'
            }
        },
        { $group: {
            count: {  _id: null, $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        { $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "count" :"$count"
            }
        }
    ])
```

**Issue**: Now considering above query, its giving me the count. But not based on only date! Its taking time as well into consideration for unique count.

**Question**: Considering the field has ISO date, Can any one tell me how to count the documents based on only date (i.e excluding time)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your two groups with

```
{$project:{day:{$dayOfMonth:'$createdDateTime'},month:{$month:'$createdDateTime'},year:{$year:'$createdDateTime'}}},
{$group:{_id:{day:'$day',month:'$month',year:'$year'}, count: {$sum:1}}}
```

You can read more about the date operators here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators

Comment: Since it gave me   `{ _id: { day: '25', month: '05', year: '2013' }, count: 31 }, { _id: { day: '26', month: '06', year: '2013' }, count: 23 },..` per every dates. I need to do second group as well with `{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1}} }`.. Thanks for your time..